# How to get the column name in Spark's map function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a wide table as a Spark dataframe (pyspark) and for every cell, I need to transform the data to be in the format column_name:column_name:value. I am trying to use a map function but I am not able to get the column name in it. Even this does not work:

```
map_dummy(c, v): 
  return c+":"+c+":"+v 

metadata.select(*(map_dummy(c, col(c)) for c in metadata.columns)).show()
```

Any idea how I can transform the data to the format I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with built-in functions:

```
metadata.select(concat(lit(c), lit(":"), lit(c), lit(":"), c)  for c in metadata.columns)).show()
```

Where concat is a function from PySpark SQL module